# npm run watch command during long time with Prestashop template

Tags: npm, prestashop

I have a folder in Prestashop 1.7 is the template Classic.
I have make a npm install command line and i have edit a file.
But when i run the command: npm run watch is stop on this:

[See the image](http://www.plixup.com/pics_core3/15139531921469captur_enpm.png)

Anyone have already this ?

Thx.